# flash builder 4 - java.lang.NullPointerException error when pressed CTL+Space (for defining skinClass)

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder, flashbuilder4

For some reason, I have started getting this weird issue when ever I try to define skinClass for my custom component.

Error message:

Problem Occured:

"Content Assist" could not complete normally. Please see the log for more information.

And the log shows these two lines

"Content Assist" did not complete normally.  Please see the log for more information.
java.lang.NullPointerException

I have googled and found some others too were getting this error message (with FB4 beta version). [Here](http://www.airtightinteractive.com/2010/01/fix-for-flash-builder-content-assist-did-not-complete-normally/), lot of people posted various methods how they resolved the issue and seems it worked for them but none of tricks has worked for me.

Some of solutions they have posted here are

> ```
> 1) Quit FB
> 2) Delete this folder: .metadata\.plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.codemodel [in the top level
> ```
>
> of your workspace folder]
>       3) Restart FB
>
> ```
>  this fix seems to be only temporary. Once I imported some new assets from an assets SWC into my project, the error re-appeared.
>
>
>  The quickest fix is to close and re-open the FB Project.]
> ```
>
> I too get this issue when I import new assets from a SWC or update a
>   SWC. To avoid having to restart Eclipse or FB4 altogether, I
>   right-click on the project I’m working on, go to properties, remove
>   the folder that contains my swcs and re-add them. It’s a pain, but
>   it’s faster doing that than quitting and restarting the IDE.
>
> I get this same error after I have updated my assets SWC and I have
>   imported folder containing SWC. If I import just SWC, i don’t get this
>   error. My fix to this is either import only SWC:s, not folders, or
>   after updating SWC (when you have imported whole folder) move some
>   item in “Build Path Libraries” list first up and then down. This
>   forces Flash Builder to update references or something. Anyways, that
>   solves the problem

It seems like all (most?) of them got this issue when they were importing new assets (which is not in my case). My case is different, not sure if it has something to do wit hit. Yesterday I installed perforce (version controlling software) and created perforce workspace to keep all my code (including flex). I added entire flex code into perforce and started working in the new perforce workspace instead of the original workspace. I checked-out only the "src" folder initially because thats the only thing I am going to make changes, but I guess it might have created problem to FB because it might require write permissions on metadata folder to save the internal information.